# Not able to stop service, stopService()-method doesn't work

Tags: android, android-service

I have two floating action buttons, one of which is used to start a service of changing wallpapers automatically and the other one is supposed to stop the service. But the problem is that the one which starts the service, functions properly but the `stopService()` method in the one used for stopping it doesn't work.

The two buttons are:

```
startService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AsyncTask asyncTask= new AsyncTask() {
                @Override
                protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
                    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "WallR"+ File.separator + "Gallery");
                    if(folder.exists()) {
                        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
                        if (listOfFiles.length != 0) {
                            getActivity().startService(intent);
                        }
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            };
            asyncTask.execute();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Automatic Wallpaper changer enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

stopService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AsyncTask asyncTask= new AsyncTask() {
                @Override
                protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
                            getActivity().stopService(intent);
                    return null;
                }
            };
            asyncTask.execute();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Automatic Wallpaper changer disabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

And the class which extends the service is as follows :-

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

/**
  * Created by abhriya on 23/10/16.
*/
public class AutomaticWallpaperChanger  extends Service {
// constant
public static final long NOTIFY_INTERVAL = 15 * 1000; // 10 seconds

// run on another Thread to avoid crash
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
// timer handling
private Timer mTimer = null;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // cancel if already existed
    if (mTimer != null) {
        mTimer.cancel();
    } else {
        // recreate new
        mTimer = new Timer();
    }
    // schedule task
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 0, NOTIFY_INTERVAL);
}

class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // run on another thread
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // display toast
                File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "WallR"+ File.separator + "Gallery");
                if(folder.exists()) {
                    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
                    if(listOfFiles.length!=0){
                        if(MainActivity.wallpaper==listOfFiles.length)
                            MainActivity.wallpaper=0;
                        Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(listOfFiles[MainActivity.wallpaper].getPath());
                        WallpaperManager mWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                        try {
                            mWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        MainActivity.wallpaper++;
                        bitmap.recycle();
                    }
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) You definitely do not need to start/stop service from AsyncTask 2) Can you post how you instantiate `intent` object?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AutomaticWallpaperChanger.class);

Comment: How do you know that the call to `stopService()` is not working?

Comment: stopService() results in false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try canceling your `TimerTask` in `onDestroy()`. You never stop the `TimerTask` from executing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not need an AsyncTask for starting/stopping a service.
Secondly, you starting a service via intent which you basically do not use.
I would try to access the service via ServiceConnection and at the moment one wants to stop the service, first you stop the timer, accessing it via the ServiceConnection(you will have to read about that - it is on the official page of Android Service) and then the service itself. The steps I recommend are:
* Start the service using a ServiceConnection, all this in a separate class.
* Store an instance of the service in the separate class after the onConnected callback comes. 
* Start the timer via a public method from the service. 
* Stop the timer via a public method from the Service. 
* Stop the service when you want via activity.

If you need to notify the UI, activity, etc, use callbacks from the Activity to the class that is in charge of starting/stopping the service.
Something similar to start:

[ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected() and startService()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222415/serviceconnection-onserviceconnected-and-startservice)

However at the code above he puts the Service logic in the activity, I was mainly suggesting to create a separate class and use a callback from the separate class to the activity in order to communicate.

Comment: Your architecture (bound service) is a bit overkill for this purpose. OP is not using an `AsyncTask` for starting/stopping the `Service`. He is using it because he is doing File I/O before starting the `Service` and that File I/O needs to be done off the main (UI) thread.

Comment: That can be, true, I forgot to add that you can use IntentService.